Apache PHP 8 keeps getting disabled
I have an Ubuntu Linux server (20.04) running Apache2 version 2.4.41
$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2024-04-10T17:46:26

with PHP8 enabled in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled:
$ ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php8*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 29 14:17 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php8.0.conf -> /etc/apache2/mods-available/php8.0.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 29 14:17 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php8.0.load -> /etc/apache2/mods-available/php8.0.load

It was running like this for months, and now somehow PHP keeps getting disabled. I become aware of it when my PHP application suddenly stops working, and when I look in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled I find the two entries for PHP8 are missing.  If I reenable it, it will run for a few days, then the same thing happens again.
I can't see anything in the logs to indicate that it has been disabled, and I am (I hope) the only person with root access to the machine.
Does anyone know how I can track down what is disabling this and why?  Is there some kind of logging I can enable to get more information?

My first idea is to make those files immutable (chattr +i file) so that even root cannot delete them. Perhaps you can find logging of the failed deletion attempt. Otherwise I have no clue right now.

Personally, I’d set up auditing:
Install the auditd package to track system changes:
sudo apt-get install auditd

Configure auditing to monitor the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled directory:
sudo auditctl -w /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ -p wx -k apache_mods

This will log any changes to the mods-enabled directory. You can check the audit logs with:
sudo ausearch -k apache_mods

Also verify PHP installation; double-check that PHP is correctly installed and configured:
sudo php -v
sudo ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/php8.0.*

If you find any issues, please share the outcome.

That's exactly what I was looking for.  I've now updated PHP to 8.2 and this hasn't happened since, so I'm thinking maybe some kind of white-hat web crawler was using some security vulnerability in PHP 8.0 and disabling it on my behalf.  I am going to drop back to 8.0 temporarily and install auditd as you suggested, and see if it happens again
